# How many face expressions did Kubo have?

Tags: production, kubo-and-the-two-strings

Since *Kubo and the Two Strings* was a stop-motion animated film based on the physical elements, approximately how many face expressions they had to 3D print for the main character?

Related [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHyTYL1Z1aM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the dot + line](https://dotandline.net/3-reasons-kubo-and-the-two-strings-is-an-animated-masterpiece-1a8e228df6ad/), they printed 23,187:

> This allowed them to layer colors during the printing of 23,187 faces without the painstaking procedure of hand painting each.

[fxguide](https://www.fxguide.com/quicktakes/kubo-and-the-two-strings-rapid-prototyping-evolves/) backs this up:

> Between the various Kubo puppets used on set, there were over 23,000 RP-printed faces.

Comment: upvote for adding references

Answer (score 3):

There were 11,007 unique mouth expressions and 4,429 brow expressions for Kubo. And with multiple Kubo puppets being used on sets there were well over 20,000 expressions printed.

Comment: You might wanna elaborate this a little. Please add relevant sources if available. Thanks.